# TypeScript: Infer type of object of generic interface implicitly from object content

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a straightforward case in TypeScript, where I have an interface with a generic type `T` that extends an enum `E`. Based on the type a config type is assigned.

```js
enum E { "A", "B" }

type ConfigsBase = { [K in E]: object }

interface Configs extends ConfigsBase {
    [E.A]: { a: string };
    [E.B]: { b: number };
}

interface MyInterface<T extends E> {
  type: T;
  config: Configs[T];
}
```

The question is how I can use this interface in a manner that the generic type is implicitly inferred from the object. So that I get useful type errors when the config is wrong.

```js
const a: ??? = {
  type: E.A,
  config: { a: 1 }, 
}
// => I want this to give a typescript error because 1 is not a string
```

What do I need to insert for `???` so that typescript gives an error that the config is wrong. It should be something like `const a: MyInterface<look for yourself what T is>`.

I found a relatively tedious solution by using an identity function which infers the type automatically:

```js
const inferType = <T extends E>(obj: MyInterface<T>): MyInterface<T> => obj

const a = inferType({
  type: E.A,
  config: { a: 1 },
})

// => TypeScript error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Is this possible to do this more elegantly with a type annotation without using a function?

Comment: Here's a playground for playing with the scenario: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeUBEBBJAaZAhJUC+AUAQC4CeADsFAMID2IAZgJYDmAzlgIZtUC8CUANoBpKExCwAugC4otAEYArYAGNi+IuOLAATg04qqdRqzZRgAD20gAJmePN2XHggJR3QmADoUMgZ1k2Yh1xFnwAbjcPQW8sP0R5WXAIeV0IgkICLV19QygAWVIASRBtPQNgAB4AFXMrUDtYAD5XdzJKWWrI9xV6R1kHU0FqyUjM3pAgsUZdaoo+KBq660aYJoAKBUVZQpKy3KrqpoBKHeLSnIqalt4WrciCCanOKH5xBln59fgotvnZbwodC-KATfr+WQARg0eGO4SAA.

Comment: Can you accept my question? I will be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a way with infer operator. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types.

You can do this:

```
enum E { "A", "B" }

type ConfigsBase = { [K in E]: object }

interface Configs extends ConfigsBase {
    [E.A]: { a: number };
    [E.B]: { b: number };
}

interface MyInterface<T extends E> {
  type: T;
  config: Configs[T];
}

type InferType<obj> = obj extends MyInterface<infer R> ? MyInterface<R> : never;

const variable = {
    type: E.A,
    config: { a: 1 }
};

const inferredVariable: InferType<typeof variable> = variable;
```

It will be faster because you don't use functions.

[Updated Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeUBEBBJAaZAhJUC+AUAQC4CeADsFAMID2IAZgJYDmAzlgIZtUC8CUANoBpKExCwAugC4otAEYArYAGNi+IuOLAATg04qqdRqzZRgAD20gAJmePN2XHggJR3QmADoUMgZ1lwCHldfABuNw9Bbyw-RHlAyBCdcIJCAi1dfUMoAFlSAEkQbT0DYAAeABVzK1A7WAA+V3cySllKiPcVekdZB1NBSskI9NaqIoZdSooKhUUm-jma63r8opLsivFJlIAlJoB+PMLirLLy-ahA4AA3XQiCbpA2dRvOHSZOeQAbPmaPMaybwodCRLo9ViyRABKAARg0eAeTxeYkYuh0wBsADV3p8fsBZBMpjNymNaAwoG8Pl9fgtKbiacAIkA)

Comment: Haha, thanks! That's a nice alternative to the function option.

Comment: however, in this case, error messages are a little bit worse (in case you leave an original type `[E.A]: { a: string };`): `Type '{ type: E; config: { a: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: Yes, this will generate never, so worse description in error will be showed. @erksch, please accept my question

Answer (score 1):

Using the *sealed class* concept is probably the cleanest and most explicit approach.
It also does not require any intermediate types or functions:

```js
enum E { "A", "B" }

interface MyTypeBase<T extends E> {
  type: T;
}

interface MyTypeA extends MyTypeBase<E.A> {
  config: { a: string };
}

interface MyTypeB extends MyTypeBase<E.B> {
  config: { b: number };
}

type MyType = MyTypeA | MyTypeB;

const a: MyType = {
  type: E.A,
  config: { a: 1 }, // <-- will give type error as expected
};
```

[In TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeUBEBBJAaZAhJUC+AUAQJYgAuwATgGYCGAxsFALICeAKqwA7Ba0DOwADzsowAB4UQAE36wAfAgJQoZbsABcUdgG4ChEuSp1GLDupRjJoWWc48+goTAB0KRfGVR6AexDViAHMtRFotfjJKUkD8PQNSChoGJjZ7XispW1T1R2FXLA8vX38gkKgAIy1wCHKqWP0iNR47dSgAXhaeSwAfTt49AmKIqDC+9qUVJs1YN3QivwDghBGtAEZ8TH0dIA)

Answer (score -1):

In kotlin you would use sealed classes:

```kotlin
sealed class Config {
    data class ConfigA(val a: String): Config()
    data class ConfigB(val b: Int): Config()
}

val a = Config.ConfigA(1)//type error here

fun main() {
    val c : Config = a

    when (c) {// no type property needed
        is Config.ConfigA -> c.a
        is Config.ConfigB -> c.b
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about TypeScript, not Kotlin.